# Outer Padding and Margins with Masonry / Isotope

Tags: jquery, width, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I have been struggling with Isotope for a while now. After a few different sittings, I can't seem to figure this one out.

**isotope.metafizzy.co/index.html**

I'll illustrate my problem with images, but here is the explanation. As you can see on my site,

**test.davewhitley.com/not-wp/isotope_test/index.php**

I am using isotope with three same-width columns.

If you look at the outer edges of the central layout, you can see that there is some padding, forcing the whole center to be somewhat narrower than the header / footer. I have played with CSS to my heart's content, but I can't figure out how to expand the central gallery to the edges of the div that it is contained it (it is 960px — therefore, the central gallery is about 940px). Normally I could do this with just divs and some CSS, but masonry's javascript is over my head (all of its calculations and such). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my problem illustrated. What I have:

http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6207/6057816365_e0b6e2e8c4.jpg

What I would like:

http://farm7.static.flickr.com/6208/6058362460_d1200a1491.jpg

Sorry for the linked images and non-hyperlinked text, I am too young on this site.

Comment: Hello, I didn't explain the basic principle of my problem. Basically, I am adding `margin-right` to each of the items in the grid. Since this is also being applied to the far right item in the far right column, the margin would break the entire column. This is because I have my outer container set at `width:960px`. I don't know how to fix this problem with jQuery Isotope.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See Masonry with gutter width mod for Isotope:

- http://isotope.metafizzy.co/tests/masonry-gutters.html
- http://metafizzy.co/blog/tests-modified-masonry-layouts

Comment: Cool, although it seems to work the same as `margin-right` or `padding-right` for me.